# Does the norm of a normed linear space determine the form of its dual spaces elements?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Hello everybody,

As an introductory example, suppose $U \subset R^n$ is open and bounded, let $p = 2$. Then there is a constant $c>0$ s.t. $\forall u \in W^{1,p}_0 : \Vert u \Vert _ {W^{1,p}_0} \le c \Vert \vert \nabla u \vert\Vert_{L^p(U)}$. This implies that the latter expression defines an equivalent norm on ${W^{1,p}_0}$.

Let $f \in L^2(U), g \in C^1(\bar{U})$. Then there exists an unique solution $u \in W^{1,p}$ to the system $ \triangle u = f $ over $U$, $u = g$ over $\partial U$ - or equivalently, there exists an unique solution $u \in W^{1,p}_0$ to the system $ \triangle u = f - \triangle g$ over $U$, (in the distributional sense).

Proof: $W^{1,2}_0$ is a Hilbert space, hence self-dual. The rhs $f - \triangle g$, defines an element of $D'$, which by density can extended to $W^{1,2}_0$. On the other side, the equivalent norm as introduced above is defined the inner product $(u,v) = \int \nabla u \cdot \nabla v$, by riesz' representation theorem, there is an $u \in W^{1,2}_0$ s.t. the induced form $(u, \cdot)$ coincides with the form defined by the rhs. But then this $u$ is a weak solution to $ \triangle u = f - \triangle g$.

So far, so good. I would like to ask some questions on this.

i) Can this be extended to other dual exponents $p$, $q$ ?

ii) The equivalent norm that regards first derivatives only is not only an equivalent norm for $p=2$, but also for $1 \leq p < \infty$. In the above case, it seems the norm imposes a form the dual vectors are subject to. I wonder whether in general - not only in the case of $L^p$ and its friends - there is some way how the form of linear functionals on some normed space $X$ are determined by the norm attached to the vector space $X$.

I hope this questions ain't too vacuous and there are interesting answers. In either case, thanks.

Comment: I've cleaned up some of the TeX, but I don't know which of several symbols you intend by "del".  Please make use of the preview feature when writing a question.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I didn't see the preview feature, maybe due to js being disabled.

Answer (score 5):

The argument you have presented is an adaptation of [the Lax-Milgram theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babu%C5%A1ka%E2%80%93Lax%E2%80%93Milgram_theorem) which is essentially equivalent to the Riesz representation theorem (and generally speaking both of these results hold only in the Hilbert space framework). The Lax-Milgram theorem fails for the Laplace equation in $L^p$-spaces with $p\neq2$. Instead, some analogous results based on the ideas of coercivity, duality and monotonicity can be obtained in any reflexive Banach space.

The Dirichlet problem for the $p$-Laplace operator
$$-\nabla(|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u)=f,\quad x\in\Omega,\qquad (*)$$
$$u=0,\qquad x\in\partial\Omega,$$
might be a "correct" $L^p$-analogue of the problem described in the question.

The right hand side of $(*)$ gives rise to the mapping $A: W_{0}^{1,p}\to(W_{0}^{1,p})^{*}$
defined by the identity
$$\langle Au,v\rangle=\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u\cdot\nabla v\ dx\quad \mbox{for all }  v\in W_{0}^{1,p}.$$
A straightforward check shows that $A$ satisfies the conditions of the following theorem
(which might be viewed as an $L^p$-analogue of the Lax-Milgram theorem).

> **Theorem.** Let $A$ be a strictly [monotone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function), [coercive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercive_function) operator from a reflexive Banach space $E$ to its dual $E^{* }$.   If $A$ is continuous on finite-dimensional subspaces of $E$ then for every $f\in E^{*}$ there exists a unique solution to the problem
>   $$Au=f.$$

Have a look at the [textbook](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WFwQ6a6fTIoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=chipot+elliptic+equations&source=bl&ots=j9iNmIjzyE&sig=I_MuBc4JWnYooBtRc9SNvHPtCGY&hl=en&ei=k6QWTM3JHcOT4ga3tsTODA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Chipot or  [the free monograph](http://www.ams.org/publications/online-books/surv49-index) by Showalter where the approach is explained in detail.